# PHP PEAR MAIL Not working with base64 image or dataurl

Tags: php, email, pear

I am trying to send dynamically created canvas object as an embedded image in mail.For that i have converted canvas to dataurl and given it to mailer library. Unfortunately it is not working with dataurl.

I tried with src having actual path and it worked but dataurl is having issue.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";
require_once 'Mail/mime.php';
$from = "xyz@gmail.com";
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$data=$_REQUEST['data']; //dataurl 
$img = $_REQUEST['body'];
$host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465";
$username = "myaccount@gmail.com";
$password = "mypassword";
$to="someone@xyz.com";
$body="<html><body><h1>Report is Here</h1><img src='cid:whatever'/></body></html>";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password));

$mime = new Mail_mime("\n");
$mime->setTXTBody("");
$mime->addHTMLImage($data, "image/png","1234.png",false,"whatever");
$mime->setHTMLBody($body);
$body = $mime->get();

$headers = $mime->headers($headers);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
;

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
 echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");

} else {
 echo("Message successfully sent");
 echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".$data."'/>";
}

?>
```

Mail sent successfully and image too rendered as i have put code at last but it doesn't appear in mail.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string, while [`addHTMLImage`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addhtmlimage.php) expects a file name or the binary contents.

Either store it in a temporary file and pass that path, or decode the base64 encoded data to binary, and pass that.